# My table rows does not echo with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am basically calling a database query on a table, but somehow only the first row is echoed out. The rest are placed below the table in one line: almost like in a `<p>` tag.

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr align="center">
<th>Company</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Job Title</th>
<th>Details</th>
<th>Contact Name</th>
<th>Contact E-mail</th>
<th>Conatct Phone</th>
<th>Documents</th> 
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {
echo "<tr align=\"center\"><td>";
        echo $row['company']; 
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $row['location'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $row['job_title'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width='270'>";
        echo  $row['details'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $row['contact_name'];
    echo "</td><br />";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $row['email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $row['phone'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href=../user-work/admin/uploads/post_id/ $row'userfile''name'> $row'userfile'</a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}
;?>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
On top of this I would like to be able to download the corresponding document relating to the job. The code to upload works fine. Just want do download it now when I view the results.

Comment: Please include the SQL query you're using as well.

Comment: Your markup is screwed up. Remove the `</table>` at the end and put it outside the loop, it might already fix the issue

Comment: You are closing your HTML table inside the while loop. So after the first row the table is finished. The rest echoed out would be invalid HTML code and so not rendered.

Comment: How many rows should the database query returns, check it?

Comment: `echo "</table>";` should not be in the loop.

Comment: @stealthyninja here is my SQL <?php
// open the connection
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXX");
 // pick the database to use
mysql_select_db("anele_testSite",$conn);
$sql = "select * from xxxx_db";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($conn);
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the table at every row.